# Django iterate over list, return seperate items in template

Tags: django, list, loops, templates

I'm new to django, so the solution I'm looking for is possibly very basic. However, I read what I could find about list iteration in templates, but I still can't seem to get it right.

I'm working on a search function that takes a query and compares it to a list of entries ('entries'). If the query is a substring of one of the entries in the list, I want to add that entry to a list ('results').
Then, I want to print the items in the list 'results' from a template.

```
def search(request):
    query = request.POST["q"]
    if util.get_entry(query) == None:
        results = ["foo", "baz"], 
        entries =  util.list_entries(),
        for entry in entries:
            if query in entry:
                    results.append(entry)
        
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
        "title": query,
        "results": results,
        "entries": entries
    })
```

and the template:

```
   <ul>
        {% for result in results %}
            <li>{{  result }}</li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <h3>For testing purposes:</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{  entry }}</li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

However, I can't get it to work. For testing purposes, I first tried printing the list of entries from the template. But in stead of printing the separate entries, it seems to print the full list:

```
    ['foo', 'baz']
    
    For testing purposes:
    
    ['CSS', 'Django', 'Git', 'HTML', 'Python']
```

When I define "results" : entries with "results: util.list_entries(), it does seem to work. Somehow, the list structure appears to get lost when I redefine it as 'entries' first. I don't understand why, so any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have trailing commas at the end of a couple of lines, this is creating tuples, remove the unnecessary commas. For example, the end of this line `entries = util.list_entries(),`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick :) I'll read up on the topic.